# SQL Injection Format Check Bypass

Tags: sql-injection

I'm doing a SQL injection test where a form value is directly being inserted into a table but it has a GUID format check on the form value like so:

"Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)."

Are there any attacks that can bypass this?

Answer (score 1):

If the application do a REAL validation on the server  with  [ [GUID Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tryparse?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Guid_TryParse_System_String_System_Guid__) ], you will have no solution.

Answer (score -1):

You should just use parameterized queries.

Pseudocode:

```
sql = "SELECT ... FROM MyTable WHERE guid = ?"
prepare(sql)
execute(guid_value)
```

Then you don't have to waste time wondering if there's an obscure case that could bypass your check.